# Angular 2 from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular

So I have a webapp that uses AngularJS. I want to change it to use Angular 2 instead (using TypeScript instead of Javascript.). I am struggling to get the following portion, as I do not know what the Angular equivalent is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The main thing is what do I do with the $scope portions that go with my new array this.books.

```
function CartController($scope) {
var store = null;
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var store = localStorage.getItem("lastName_cart");
}
if(store != null) {
    $scope.books = JSON.parse(store);
} else {
$scope.books = 
[{ title: 'Absolute Java', qty: 1, price: 114.95},
 { title: 'Pro HTML5', qty: 1, price: 27.95},
 { title: 'Head First HTML5', qty: 1, price: 27.89}];
} 
 $scope.total = 114.95 + 27.95 + 27.89;


$scope.removeBook = function(index) {
    $scope.books.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.updateTotal();
}

$scope.updateTotal = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.books.length; i++) {
        sum += $scope.books[i].price * $scope.books[i].qty; 
    }
    $scope.total = sum;
}
```

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are the *same thing*

Comment: In 2014, Google announced Angular 2. It is rebranded and repurposed. The ‘JS’ letters for JavaScript is dropped from its brand, as TypeScript becomes its preferred dialect.

Comment: I'm aware the product was renamed.Then change your question to say you're changing from Angular 1 to Angular 2.  As written you're changing from Angular to Angular which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I just realized AngularJS is also called Angular 1 while doing more research. Sorry, it is now fixed.

Comment: I've come to the party and gone straight to Angular 4. So I'm not au fait with AngularJS. I take it you've perused: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade  https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference  - I recall seeing that when I started learning. Hope that gives you what your after... 
bindToController: {}. Component inputs and outputs should be bound to the controller instead of using the $scope.

Comment: Those are great resources. I will check them out.

Comment: Angular uses lexical scoping. Remove references to $scope and replace it with "this" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Angular JS and Angular is completely different.
angular using typescript and it is component based . there is no controller.

and your code should be like this in angular 2 or 4

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-cart',
      templateUrl: './cart.component.html'
   })
  export class CartComponent {
       store = null;
       book = [];
       total: Number;
 constructor() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            this.store = localStorage.getItem("lastName_cart");
        }
       if(this.store != null) {
         this.books = JSON.parse(store);
       } else {
           this.books = 
              [{ title: 'Absolute Java', qty: 1, price: 114.95},
              { title: 'Pro HTML5', qty: 1, price: 27.95},
              { title: 'Head First HTML5', qty: 1, price: 27.89}];
          } 
       this.total = 114.95 + 27.95 + 27.89;
     }
   removeBook(index) {
      this.books.splice(index, 1);
      this.updateTotal();
   }
   updateTotal() {
     let sum = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.books.length; i++) {
       sum += this.books[i].price * this.books[i].qty; 
     }
    this.total = sum;
   }
 }
```

Comment: *there is no controller*, you are wrong mate, the component class is the controller, the template is the view, controller + template = component

Comment: i mean there is no controller like what was in angular 1 . he is new in angular 2 that is why i have answered like that buddy @Dummy

Answer (score 0):

[useful helper how migrate your applications from angular 1.x to angular 2](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/migrate/)